# Passing JSON to WebService

Tags: java, json, web-services, dropwizard

I have developed a webservice in java using dropwizard framework. I want it to consume a json.

My Service code is  -

-- Resource Class

```
@Path(value = "/product")
  public class ProductResource{ 

   @POST
   @Path(value = "/getProduct")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Product getProduct(InputBean bean) {
    // Just trying to print the parameters. 
    System.out.println(bean.getProductId());
    return new Product(1, "Product1-UpdatedValue", 1, 1, 1);
   }
}
```

-- InputBean is a simple bean class.

```
public class InputBean {

    private int productId;
    private String productName;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName= productName;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId= productId;
        }
}
```

---

Client Code -

```
    public String getProduct() {

            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/product/getProduct");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject ("{\"productId\": 1, \"productName\": \"Product1\"}");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, data);
            return response.getEntity(String.class);
        }
```

I'm getting an error -

**ClientHandlerException**

Is there anything wrong with this piece of code?

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject ("{\"productId\": 1, \"productName\": \"Product1\"}");
ClientResponse response =  webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .post(ClientResponse.class, data);
```

Can someone please point me what I might be missing?

CLIENT LOGS -

[image]

Comment: Please post the logs from the server. Also, where is that `WebResource` class from?

Comment: Added logs... I'm using dropwizard framework, its the resource class from it.

Comment: The log shows that your class is being sent to the server as an `application/octet-stream`. For future debugging, try using a browser-based REST client to send requests like this manually to try to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Looks like DropWizard doesn't bother to post their Javadocs online, so I'm not going to be able to go find that class myself. My guess is that that `type` method doesn't set the content type of the request body.

Comment: oh ok.. i think i am trying to match the correct type in the client code... by setting it to APPLICATION_JSON... somehow not setting it seems.. i'll concentrate a bit there.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the type correctly and making the request correctly.

The problem is you have nothing to handle the response.

```
A message body reader for Java class my.class.path.InputBean
```

...is basically saying, you're returning something that cannot be read, formatted, and ouputted to anything useful.

You're returning a Product type in your service, which is your octet-stream, but I don't see where you have a MessageBodyWriter to output this response to JSON.

You need:

```
 @Provider
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
public static class ProductWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Product>
{
    @Override
    public long getSize(Product data, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation annotations[], MediaType mediaType)
    {
        // cannot predetermine this so return -1
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        if ( mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE) )
        {
            return Product.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Product data, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers, OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        if ( mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE) )
        {
            outputToJSON( data, out );
        }
    }
    private void outputToJSON(Product data, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"))
        {
            gson.toJson( data, w );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh so the problem is at the point where i'm returning the product from service method?! here - > `return new Product(1, "Product1-UpdatedValue", 1, 1, 1);` ?

Comment: This class which you mentioned needs to be implemented in service code? what should i give in client code when reading a json? Is `response.getEntity(String.class);` correct?

Comment: I'm using Jackson for JSON serialization, so i guess, that is not a problem. I even tested out removing the consumes functionality using postman and the webservice does print a json object.

Bottomline, the webservice is able to produce a json, just not able to consume it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JSONObject cannot be serialized, because no message writer could be found. Why don't you just give the InputBean as input?

Change your client code to:

```
public String getProduct() {

        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource =       client.resource("http://localhost:8080/product/getProduct");
        InputBean data = new InputBean(1,1); // make sure there's a constructor
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, data);
        return response.getEntity(String.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard preferes Jackson for JSON serialization & deserialization, in which case you should be able to pass InputBean directly, you can also specify the mime type manually or use the Entity wrapper, e.g.

```
    final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
            .using(config.getJerseyClientConfiguration())
            .build("jersey-client");
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/product/getProduct");
    InputBean data = new InputBean(1,1);
    String response = webResource.post(String.class, Entity.json(data));
```

See http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/client.html#jersey-client for details on how to create a configured Jersey client.